# Scale Animation for listItem

Tags: java, android, focus, android-animation, onitemselectedlistener

I have a `ListView`. I know how to highlight or change the background of a selected item in a ListView. 
But **I want to scale the selected item** like this:

(selected item is a little bigger than other list items in this picture)

[image]

Can anyone help me to do that?

Comment: use ViewGroup.getChildStaticTransformation()

Comment: @pskink Where should i write this code ???

Comment: as the documentation says: "subclasses may override this method for different behavior"

Comment: @pskink Could you please give me an example of how to do that ?

Comment: scale the Matrix in the Transformation

Comment: Hello, have you solved this issue. I need the same thing, selected item should be bigger and a little above other elements, like it is floating a little above.

Comment: @Veljko please take a look at my answer. It may help you ;)

Comment: Its been 2 years :) but tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, I set `OnFocusChangeListener` for List items and set animation for them:

```
OnFocusChangeListener itemFocusChangeListener = new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                int focus = 0;
        if (hasFocus) {
            focus = R.anim.enlarge;
        } else {
            focus = R.anim.decrease;
        }
        Animation mAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                getActivity().getApplication(), focus);
        mAnimation.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        mAnimation.setFillAfter(hasFocus);
        v.startAnimation(mAnimation);
        mAnimation.start();
        v.bringToFront();
    }
};
```

enlarg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding= "UTF-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
<scale
    android:duration="100"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50.0%"
    android:pivotY="50.0%"
    android:repeatCount="0"
    android:toXScale="1.15"
    android:toYScale="1.15" />
```

decrease.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="false"
android:fillBefore="true"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >

<scale
    android:duration="100"
    android:fromXScale="1.1"
    android:fromYScale="1.1"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50.0%"
    android:pivotY="50.0%"
    android:repeatCount="0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />
```

Comment: how have you added OnFocusChangeListener for list items

Comment: @avik Yes as I wrote before I've added OnFocusChangeListener for list items.